# PowerShell Get-Help does not recognize parameter comments

Tags: powershell

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1) (among others), I've been trying to get Powershell's Get-Help to recognize function parameter comments but can't get it to work. 
For example, the following function uses the .PARAMETER keyword

```
function Add-Extension
{
param ([string]$Name,[string]$Extension = "txt")
$name = $name + "." + $extension
$name

<#
.SYNOPSIS

Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.

.DESCRIPTION

Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.
Takes any strings for the file name or extension.

.PARAMETER Name
Specifies the file name.

.PARAMETER Extension
Specifies the extension. "Txt" is the default.

#>
}
```

while the following uses comment text before the parameter name.

```
function Add-Extension
{
param
(

    [string]
    #Specifies the file name.
    $name,

    [string]
    #Specifies the file name extension. "Txt" is the default.
    $extension = "txt"
)

$name = $name + "." + $extension
$name

<#
.SYNOPSIS

Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.

.DESCRIPTION

Adds a file name extension to a supplied name. Takes any strings for the
file name or extension.

#>
}
```

Both are based on Microsoft examples (cut here for brevity but I've tested the full example code also) and both should return parameter info using Get-Help. Instead I get the following results to the command `Get-Help Add-Extension`:

```
NAME
    Add-Extension

SYNOPSIS
    Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.


SYNTAX
    Add-Extension [[-name] <String>] [[-extension] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Adds a file name extension to a supplied name. Takes any strings for the
    file name or extension.


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Add-Extension -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Add-Extension -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Add-Extension -full".
```

No sign of any parameter info. 
Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the parameter details, you apparently need to use the `-detailed` or `-full` switch, i.e., `Get-Help Add-Extension -detailed`.  When I do that with your code from the first example, I get

```
PS D:\Scripts> Get-Help Add-Extension -detailed

NAME
    Add-Extension

SYNOPSIS
    Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.


SYNTAX
    Add-Extension [[-Name] <String>] [[-Extension] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Adds a file name extension to a supplied name.
    Takes any strings for the file name or extension.


PARAMETERS
    -Name <String>
        Specifies the file name.

    -Extension <String>
        Specifies the extension. "Txt" is the default.

    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Add-Extension -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Add-Extension -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Add-Extension -full".
```

The Microsoft documentation is not clear about this.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed does it. The -detailed switch is not mentioned in the article at all. The -full switch is mentioned in relation to getting a parameter attribute table only. I left a comment to that effect, maybe it will even be addressed. Appreciate your time.